# Menu bar class=active bootstrap theme not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site and i am working in php html css javascript/jquery
i am using bootstrap theme for the first time. Its so good using bootstrap but i have a problem in menu bar navigation active link

even if i add a jquery changing a active class it doesnot work .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Real Estate</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css"/>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/script.js"></script>

<!-- Owl stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">
<script src="assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<!-- Owl stylesheet -->


<!-- slitslider -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/slitslider/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/slitslider/css/custom.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/slitslider/js/modernizr.custom.79639.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/slitslider/js/jquery.ba-cond.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/slitslider/js/jquery.slitslider.js"></script>
<!-- slitslider -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $('#username').hover(
                function (){
                    $('#submenu').css("display", "block");
                     /*$('#submenu').css("background-color", "#999");
                     $('#submenu').css("color", "#000");*/
                     $('#submenu').css("z-index", "1");
                },
                function () {
                    $('#submenu').css("display", "none");
                }
            );


        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>


    <!-- Header Starts -->
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">

            <div class="navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
              <div class="container">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
       <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
             data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

       </div>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="agent.html">Agents</a></li>
             <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
             <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>

             <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Your Name<b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                   <li><a href="register.php">Edit Profile</a></li>
                   <li><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
                </ul>
             </li>

                <li><a href="login.php">Log in</a></li>
                <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>

       </div>
    </nav>

              </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    <!-- #Header Starts -->





    <div class="container">

    <!-- Header Starts -->
    <div class="header">
    <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Realestate"></a>
         <ul class="pull-right" style="margin-top:10px;">
             <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Home
                </a>
                <?php if (!empty($_SESSION['uname'])) { ?>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                   <li><a href="homesaleAdd.php">Add Property</a></li>
                        <li><a href="selectpropertyHome.php">Edit Property</a></li>
                </ul>
                 <?php } ?>  </li>   
              <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Land
                </a>
                <?php if (!empty($_SESSION['uname'])) { ?>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                   <li><a href="landsaleAdd.php">Add Property</a></li>
                        <li><a href="selectpropertyLand.php">Edit Property</a></li>
                </ul>
              <?php } ?></li>
          </ul>

                 <!-- <div id ="salesBranch" style="display:none">
                                <div> <a href="saleAdd.php">Add Property</a> </div> <div> <a href="saleEdit.php">Edit Property</a> </div> -->
                            </div>
    </div>
    <!-- #Header Starts -->
    </div>
```

i added following jquery to change the active class but also its not working properly

```
$(".nav a").on("click", function(){
               $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
               $(this).parent().addClass("active");
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be because your menu loads different pages than the one you are on. You need to set the active class on the appropriate nav link on page load. For example you could test if the href of the link is the same as the current page name and add class "active" if it is.